# Calling custom method of a class compiled at runtime

Tags: java

I have a java source code which would be compiled at runtime. 
I'm compiling the source code (present as a string) and loading it to a class as below :

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());


        // Load and instantiate compiled class.
        URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("TakeAdvantageOftMapComponents", true, classLoader);
```

This class contains a method which I need to call named `runJob`. Normally I'd do it like:

```
TakeAdvantageOftMapComponents c  = new TakeAdvantageOftMapComponents();
c.runJob(new string[]);
```

Now this same method is present in the class which I compile at runtime. But how do I call it ?

Comment: I figured it out using Relection - based on an answer given here :I figured it out using Relection - based on an answer given [here][1]

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Better than **using reflection** to call the method you want, you might want to **declare an `interface`** that your class would extend, such as:

```
package ccjmne;

public interface JobRunner {

    public void runJob(final String[] args);
}
```

... and make your class **implement** that `interface`:

File: */home/eric/stackoverflow/A.java*

```
package stackoverflow;

public class A implements ccjmne.JobRunner {
    public void runJob(final String args[]) {
        for(final String str : args) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, load that class as follows:

```
final Class<JobRunner> cls = (Class<JobRunner>) Class.forName("stackoverflow.A", true, classLoader);
```

Note that I know that I've a `JobRunner` here.

Thus, I can simply do:

```
cls.newInstance().runJob("Hello world!".split(" "));
```

... And you're done!

---

Sample working code:

```
package ccjmne;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JobRunnerTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, MalformedURLException {
        final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        final File root = new File("/home/eric/");
        compiler.run(null, null, null, root + "/stackoverflow/A.java");
        final URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });
        final Class<JobRunner> cls = (Class<JobRunner>) Class.forName("stackoverflow.A", true, classLoader);
        cls.newInstance().runJob("Hello world!".split(" "));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
world!
```

Comment: This would have worked - but I have no control over the source. It's being generated by an external program. But up-voting for the detailed answer.